# How do browsers handle non-cacheable resources that are referenced more than once?

Tags: html, http, caching, browser, browser-cache

[This](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_dupes) Yahoo Developer Network article says that browsers handle non-cacheable resources that are referenced more than once in a single HTML differently. I didn't find any rule about this in the [HTTP/1.1 cache RFC](http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-22.txt).

I made some experiments in Chrome, but I couldn't figure out the exact rules. It was loading a duplicate non-cacheable scripts tag only once. Then I referenced the same script in 3 iframes. The first one triggered a network request, but the others were served from the cache. I tried to reference the same url as the src of an image, and that triggered a network reques again.

Is there any documentation about this behavior? How does this differ between browsers?

Comment: How did you trigger the no cache state?

Comment: I use a HTTP proxy to add "Cache-Control: max-age=0" header.

Comment: Maybe the browser just sees the time of the first request of the page and uses that exact time for subsequent calls for the additional files.

Comment: Hm, and what about the iframes? Those were requested separately, so the timestamp should differ, still no request is made for the second and the third iframe (but the first triggers a request despite the script was already referenced in the main page).

Comment: Could you add a timestamp (with microtime) of the page generation time as GET variable to file request in your iframe html code? And then see, if they differ?

Answer (score 3):

When a client decides to retrieve a resource, it's [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) that governs that rules of whether that resource can be returned from a cache, or needs to be revalidated/reloaded from the origin server (mostly [section 14.9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) but you really need to read the whole thing) .

However, when you have multiple copies of the same resource on the same page, after the first copy has been retrieved following the rules of RFC2616, the decision as to whether to retrieve additional copies is now covered by the HTML5 spec (mostly specified in the [processing model for fetching resources](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#processing-model)).

In particular, note step 10:

> If the resource [...] is already being downloaded for other reasons (e.g. another invocation of this algorithm), and this request would be identical to the previous one (e.g. same Accept and Origin headers), and the user agent is configured such that it is to reuse the data from the existing download instead of initiating a new one, then use the results of the existing download instead of starting a new one.

This clearly describes a number of factors that could come into play in deciding whether a resource may be reused or not. Some key points:

- **Same Accept and Origin headers**: While most browsers use the same `Accept` headers everywhere, in Internet Explorer  they're different for an image vs a script vs HTML. And every browser sends a different `Referer` when frames are involved, and while `Referer` isn't directly mentioned, `Accept` and `Origin` were only given as examples.
- **Already being downloaded**: Note that that is something quite different from *already downloaded*. So if the resource occurs multiple times on the page, but the first occurrence is finished downloading before the second occurrence is encountered, then the option to reuse may not be applicable.
- **The user agent is configured to reuse the data**: That implies to me that the decision to reuse or re-retrieve the data is somewhat at the discretion of the user-agent, or at least a user option.

The end result, is that every single browser handles caching slightly differently. And even in a particular browser, the results may differ based on timing.

I created a test case with three nested frames (i.e. a page containing an `iframe`, which itself contained an `iframe`) and 6 copies of the same script, 2 on each page (using `Cache-Control:no-cache` to make them non-cacheable, but also tested with other variations, including `max-age=0`).

- Chrome loaded only 1 copy.
- Internet Explorer tended to vary, assumedly based on load, but was between 1 and 3.
- Safari loaded 3 copies, one for each frame (i.e. with different `Referer` headers).
- Opera and Firefox loaded all 6 copies.

When I reused the same resource in a couple of images (one on the root page, one in the first `iframe`) and a couple of other images for reference, the behaviour changed.

- Chrome now loaded 5 copies, 1 of each type on each page. While `Accept` headers in Chrome are the same for images and scripts, the header *order* is different, which suggests they may be treated differently, and potentially cached differently.
- Internet Explorer loaded 2 copies, 1 of each type which was to be expected for them. Assumedly that could have varied though, given their behaviour when it was just scripts.
- Safari was still only 3 copies, one per frame.
- Opera was inexplicably still 6. Couldn't tell what portion of those were scripts and which were images. But possibly this is also something that could vary based on load or timing.
- Firefox loaded 8 copies, which was to be expected for them. The 6 scripts, plus the 2 new images.

Now this was what happened when viewing the page normally - i.e. just entering the page url into the address bar. Forcing a reload with F5 (or whatever the equivalent on Safari) produced a whole different set of results. And in general, the whole concept of reloading, F5 vs Ctrl-F5, what headers get sent by the client, etc. also differs wildly from one browser to the next. But that's a subject for another day.

The bottom line is caching is very unpredictable from one browser to the next, and the specs somewhat leave it up to the implementors to decide what works best for them.

I hope this has answered your question.

**Additional Note:** I should mention that I didn't go out of my way to test the latest copy of every browser (Safari in particular was an ancient v4, Internet Explorer was v9, but the others were probably fairly up to date). I doubt it makes much difference though. The chances that all browsers have suddenly converged on consistent behaviour in this regard is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Molnarg, if you read the article properly it will become clear why this happens.

> Unnecessary HTTP requests happen in Internet Explorer, but not in
> Firefox. In Internet Explorer, if an external script is included twice
> and is not cacheable, it generates two HTTP requests during page
> loading. Even if the script is cacheable, extra HTTP requests occur
> when the user reloads the page.

This behavior is unique to Internet Explorer only. If you ask me why this happens, I would say that IE developers chose to ignore the [HTTP/1.1 cache RFC](http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-22.txt) or at least could not implement it. Maybe it is a work in progress. But then again there are lot of aspects wherein IE is different from most of the browsers (JavaScript, HTML5, CSS ). This can't be helped unless devs update it.

The Yahoo Dev Article you [gave](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_dupes) lists best practices for high performance. This must accommodate for all the IE users, which are impaired by this. Which is why including same script multiple times, though OK for other browsers hurts IE users and should be avoided.

#### Update

Non-cacheable resources will generate network request, once or multiple times alike.

From **2. Overview of Cache Operation** from the [HTTP/1.1 cache RFC](http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-22.txt)

> Although caching is an entirely OPTIONAL feature of HTTP, we assume
> that reusing the cached response is desirable and that such reuse
> is the default behavior when no requirement or locally-desired
> configuration prevents it.

So using cache means attempting to reuse and non-cacheable means opposite. Think of it like this non-cacheable request is like HTTP request with cache turned off (fallback from HTTP with cache on).

Cache-Control: max-age=n does not prevent cache storing it merely states that cache item is stale after n seconds. To prevent using cache use these headers for image:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you point out where the cache RFC specifies this behaviour? I couldn't find it. I know the recommended best practices, but I'm specifically interested in browser behaviour when you reference something non-cacheable more than once. As I pointed out in the question, the rules are not very straight-forward even in standards compliant browsers, that's why I was asking for references to documentation about this.